# Is the DataMapper available throughout Mule Future enterprise edition?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have doubt, current version we have DataWeaver which is similar to Datamapper for transformation.
If we need, require to add as a plugin.

In this link https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/datamapper-user-guide-and-reference#examples says Datamapper is exclusive to entreprsie edtion only.

Is the Datamapper can be used throughout the future version of enterprise edition completely ( either as Plugin for standalone or default for cloudhub?.
Is it have a any chance of deprecating in future for enterprise version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataMapper will be supported till Mule runtime version 4.0 , if you start off new i would recommend going with DataWeave. Otherwise you'll need to migrate at a later moment

Comment: This is accurate, but I might add that Mulesoft has announced that Mule 3.5 and Mule 3.8 will be "long term supported" versions, meaning 4 years from release date.  So you can run applications using Data Mapper on a supported runtime until 2021.  Here's the link to the policy: https://www.mulesoft.com/legal/versioning-back-support-policy